# SiteMap definition in new UI for 2017 R2

Tags: acumatica

Is there documentation available as to how to configure the menu for new pages/modules in the new UI?
The Sitemap definition from page SM200520 works correctly only when the classic UI is used.

Thanks

Comment: worth mentioning if you are upgrading a customization package to 2017R2, you need to manually delete and then re-add your sitemap entries after you configured the new menu UI to get the correct entries in your customization package. Reload from Database will not work (as of 17.200.0401)

Comment: good to know this. Thanks @Brendan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acumatica Online Help has several how-to articles on customizing the New UI (aka Modern User Interface) here:

https://help.acumatica.com/(W(1))/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=774107f8-a149-4676-9c78-0c884edd19cb

If you need something more it'd be handy if you explained your goals more specifically.

Comment: Thanks Alex. We were able to configure the site map in the new UI. However, the new workspace is always shown in the bottom. 
The Edit Menu option appears to allow to drag the workspace to a higher  section but after pressing "Exit Edit Menu" it goes back to the bottom.
[Editing the Menu](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cff4yd4d3z404pi/Editing%20the%20Menu.png?dl=0)
and 
[Final Result](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1m305cm0ugsj6js/Final%20Result.png?dl=0)

Comment: I just saw it's done with the pin option in the upper right side.